# Impedindo múltiplas thread para a mesma rotina e o mesmo utilizador?

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Estou a desenvolver uma app para a web em `ASP.NET Core MVC` e algumas rotinas são chamadas carregando num botão na página da web.

Acontece que é possível carregar neste botão múltiplas vezes, pelo que preciso de algum que `bloqueie/suspenda/...` threads indesejadas.

Tentei fazer isso com este código (`C#`), onde a variável `User` é uma variável de sessão, correspondente ao utilizador:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendOrdForm(
    int id, 
    ProdListViewModel model, 
    IFormCollection form
)
{
    UserModel user = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<UserModel>("User");
    if (user.AwaitingOrderSubmit)
        while (true); // blocks thread or aborts it... What's the best option?

    user.AwaitingOrderSubmit = true;
    HttpContext.Session.SetJson("User", user);
    
    // ... the rest of the long and time-expensive routine ...
    user.AwaitingOrderSubmit = false;
    HttpContext.Session.SetJson("User", user);
    return RedirectToAction("");
}
```

Como posso tornar este código só executável uma vez por `thread` e utilizador, através de código nesta rotina ou em outra?

Comment: não entendi bem, mas aparentemente injetar o seu serviço como scoped ja resolveria, ja que cada requisição traria uma instancia diferente do serviço

Comment: O que você quer dizer com carregar o botão múltiplas vezes? Você quer bloquear o click dele até que a rotina seja concluída?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo : eu sei bloquear o botão na UI. Já fiz um modal que bloqueia a página. No entanto do lado do server, uma solução que bloqueie a rotina é mais segura. Para clickar o botão múltiplas vezes, qualquer for loop que clique no botão várias vezes o faz. Se a UI não estiver bloqueada é ainda mais fácil: basta num curto intervalo de tempo clickar no botão, enquanto a aplicação está a "pensar"...

Comment: @LucasMiranda: dois cliques no mesmo botão é o mesmo http request? Podia-me indicar como injectar um serviço no Startup.cs que é um simples controller da app principal...?

Comment: @JDias Nesse caso, não é apenas com o escopo de serviço que você vai resolver, vai precisar adicionar um controle lógico para definir se a rotina pode ou não ser executada, por já existir outro processamento em execução.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Quais são as palavras chave para procurar na net? Algum link com exemplo?

Comment: @JDias o que você está procurando é "Controle de Concorrência"